# Showing '$' sign and 3 decimal places in money

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, data-annotations, telerik-mvc

I'm currently working on displaying the "$" sign in some Telerik Numberic Text Boxes at the moment.  I noticed that there is a Currency Text Box and used that and it did as I wanted but with one issue.  I no longer can see 3 decimal places back.  I've tried changing the format string to allow me to but it makes no difference.  Here is what I have so far.

By the way, I am using Telerik MVC Extensions in case anyone was curious.

Model

```
[NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Products.Variants.Fields.Price")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.000}")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.Telerik().CurrencyTextBoxFor(model => model.Price) [@Model.PrimaryStoreCurrencyCode]
```

I want to be able to display the $ sign plus go 3 decimal places back within the editor.

Comment: is this the old Telerik MVC extensions, or the KendoUI.  I think it's the older MVC extensions, right?

Comment: Yeah, it's MVC extensions.  Sorry about that.  I'll make the edit.